# How to search for an element in a slice and compare it with a variable

Tags: go, if-statement, slice

I want to create a simple logic were:

```
if stringCatchedFromBodyJSON != stringStoragedInMySlice {
//Do stuff
}else{
//Do more stuff
}
```

I have tried:

```
if !storage.Contains(database.USER, stringCatchedFromBodyJSON){ //Says ".Contains" isn't declared}
if stringCatchedFromBodyJSON != dataBaseUsers { //Force databaseUsers to string = "" intead of comparing}
```

Created a function to return true if stringCatchedFromBodyJSON is equal to stringStoragedInMySlice but the program crashes when entering the function:

```
if itemExists(storage, stringCatchedFromBodyJSON) == true {}

func itemExists(arrayType interface{}, item interface{}) bool {
    arr := reflect.ValueOf(arrayType)

    if arr.Kind() != reflect.Array {
        panic("Invalid data-type")
    }

    for i := 0; i < arr.Len(); i++ {
        if arr.Index(i).Interface() == item {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

I have this arraylist:

```
func arrayList() {
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Max", PASSWORD: "1234"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Rob", PASSWORD: "5678"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Lee", PASSWORD: "9101"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Joe", PASSWORD: "1213"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "May", PASSWORD: "1415"})
}
```

And this structure:

```
type Database struct {
    USER     string `json:"user"`
    PASSWORD string `json:"password"`
}
```

I have managed to add an new "user" by mocking on the Body of my Put HTTP Method using Postman and IT WORKS:

```
{
    "name":"Moe",
    "id":"1234"
}
```

I can't create an if statement to keep the repeated names to be added on the slice.

If you want to see my whole program, here you go!:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    stringCatchedFromBodyJSON    string
    IDString         string
    storageConvertedToBytes []byte
    err                     error

    msg Message

    database Database
    storage  []Database
)

// Message is were body.json of method POST will be located.
type Message struct {
    NAME string `json:"name"`
    ID   string `json:"id"`
}

// Database is an example of a database
type Database struct {
    USER     string `json:"user"`
    PASSWORD string `json:"password"`
}

// You can add or remove manually this lines of code in order to edit the slice.
func arrayList() {
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Max", PASSWORD: "1234"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Rob", PASSWORD: "5678"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Lee", PASSWORD: "9101"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "Joe", PASSWORD: "1213"})
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: "May", PASSWORD: "1415"})
}

func put(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "PUT" {
        _, err = json.Marshal(storage)
        arrayList()

        // Read body.
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        defer r.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
            return
        }

        // Unmarshal.
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &msg)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
            return
        }

        stringCatchedFromBodyJSON = msg.NAME
        IDString = msg.ID

        if stringCatchedFromBodyJSON != database.USER {
            storage = append(storage, Database{USER: stringCatchedFromBodyJSON, PASSWORD: IDString})
            storageConvertedToBytes, _ = json.Marshal(storage)
            w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
            w.Write(storageConvertedToBytes)
        } else {
            w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
            w.Write([]byte("User already exist"))
        }

    } else {
        w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte("Wrong http method"))
    }
}

func main() {
    PORT := ":8000"
    http.HandleFunc("/put", put)
    log.Println("Starting server on address", PORT)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use reflection for such task. Write a normal function.

Comment: The function itemExists explicitly panics when the argument is not an array. Did you intend to check for a slice: `if arr.Kind() != reflect.Slice { panic("Invalid data-type") }`

Comment: I managed to do it with a FOR function, i created the function to compare my variable with all users presented in my slice and if my variable isn't equal to any users, add my variable with its ID in the slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function i implemented to resolve this problem was:

```
func searchForName() bool {
    for i := range storage {
        if storage[i].USER == stringCatchedFromBodyJSON {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I implemented this function inside the if statement:

```
stringCatchedFromBodyJSON = msg.NAME
IDString = msg.ID
if searchForName() == false {
    storage = append(storage, Database{USER: stringCatchedFromBodyJSON, PASSWORD: IDString})
    storageConvertedToBytes, _ = json.Marshal(storage)
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    w.Write(storageConvertedToBytes)
} else {
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte("User already exist"))
}
```

This is how i sort out my problem.